# Implementation for a Translationally Invariant Algorithm

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, oracles

I'm working on inserting an item into a sorted list https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9901059.pdf.
I would like to know how to implement this formula with Qiskit or just the circuit representing it :

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Quantum Fourier Transform (QFT) on $n$ qubits is the operation

$$|\textbf{p}\rangle \mapsto \frac{1}{2^{n/2}} \sum_{x=0}^{2^n - 1} e^{2\pi i\textbf{p}x / 2^n} |x\rangle$$

If $N = 2^{n}$ then we will get the transformation you are asking for if you use $n + 1$ instead of $n$. The class [QFT](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.QFT.html) is the Qiskit's implementation of this transformation.

So, the circuit can be created as follows, using the assumption that $N = 2^{n}$:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import QFT

circ = QFT(n + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much